# Selenium can't find element by name: NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, automation, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to learn Python better by doing automation. My project right now is creating a bot that will log in to Instagram. My code is as follows:

```py
def login(self):
    self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')

    self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
    self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[4]').click
```

I am positive that the name for at least the password and username are correct, but even when I test those alone I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="username"]"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The name might be correct, but are you confident the page that is displayed in *your* browser of choice is the *exact* same as the page presented to Selenium? I would imagine a product like Instagram is loaded with anti-automation features to prevent this sort of behavior.

Comment: Check if the elements are wrapped in iframe, if that's the case then you have to `driver.switch_to.frame` method with either frame index/id/name attribute or frame element.

Comment: @esqew Yes. The code I have written will load the Instagram login, and the element names are the same on that one as the one that I manually search for.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The web page wasn't loading fast enough. By having the program sleep for two seconds it fixed it.